# How to annualize the correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, asset-returns, correlation-matrix, annualized

If asset returns are daily, and the asset return covariance matrix, $\Sigma$, is annualized by $\Sigma \times 252$, do I also multiply the correlation matrix by 252 to annualize it?

Comment: I posted a the new answer below. If you thing it is the best answer, please mark it as such. I discuss 252 instead of the Sqrt(252) as you suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because correlation is a unitless quantity. As you use volatilities to do the scaling, the $\sqrt{252}$ factor should already be taken into account in them.

If you take a correlation of 1 between two assets, multiplying your correlation matrix by a factor $C \neq 1$ risks either to underestimate correlations (by hiding perfect (anti)correlations) or have your matrix not making any sense (correlation greater than 1).

Comment: To make it easy to understand, recall that correlation is $\frac{cov(x,y)}{\sqrt{var(x) var(y)}}$. So, the $252$ in the numerator and denominator will simplify.

Comment: Why would it also be in the denominator

Comment: Hi: It's in the denominator because the variances are in the diagonals of the covariance matrix so they need to be multiplied by the same factor.  But I think it's better to think of it the following way: covariance is the analogue of variance so it increases with time. On the other hand, correlation doesn't increase with time so there's no need to do anything to it. Whether one measures it over a year or a day shouldn't change it.

Comment: The above is technically correct, but correlation of daily returns will not necessarily be equal to the correlation of annual returns. The role of random variation (noise) in returns diminishes over longer periods as the signal accumulates, and correlations get stronger.

Comment: @siou0107 If you're sure that covariance has units, you could also answer this https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57417/interpretation-and-units-of-a-covariance-element-in-portfolio-risk

Comment: @byouness regarding your first comment here, I should correct the question to say that, it is not being suggested as a sequential  procedure for the covariance matrix to be annualized by the 252 factor prior to the annualization of the correlation matrix. I was just asking if the multiplication procedure used for covariance also applies to correlation, stand-alone

Comment: @develarist, Some important things to keep in mind: (1) correlations are between $-1$ and $1$, if you multiply by $\sqrt{252}$ it won't be a correlation anymore. (2) the rescaling by this $\sqrt{252}$ doesn't work if there is autocorrelation or mean-reversion, works only when iid. (3) To answer your question why it should be applied to the denominator as well, if the increments are iid, then it applies to the covariance but also the variance (particular case as $var(x) = cov(x, x)$).

Comment: why discuss $\sqrt{252}$ instead of $252$?

Comment: @byouness In my answer below, I expanded your comment.

Comment: @markleeds I expand your intuition in the secod comment of my anwer below.

Comment: @RichardHardy In the the Note 1 of my answer below I tried to give sufficiant conditions for the scaling with the period of the returns. Are they enough?

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo, I get the absence of autocorrelations but am not entirely sure what you mean by *given an arbitrary period to measure returns, the covariances are the same whatever the start of such period*.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for your reply! By period or a return I mean the distance of time between the two prices used to compute the return. Please see the enphasized previous use of the word *previous* in the same sentence. I will be gratefull if you tell me a better word to use or a better way to rephrase the explanation to make it more precise and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

No.

By definition,

```
Corr[x, y] = Cov[x, y] / Sqrt( Var[x] Var[y] )
```

where `x` and `y` are the **daily** returns of two assets.

If annualizing the (variance and) covariance matrix of daily returns requires multiplication by 252, then the correlation of **annual** annual returns `X` and `Y` is

```
Corr[X, Y] = Cov[X, Y] / Sqrt( Var[X] Var[X] ) = 252 Cov[x, y] / Sqrt( 252 Var[x] 252 Var[y] )
```

because *variances* and *covariances* are the elements of the covariance matrix.

Canceling 252^2 inside que square root and 252 in the numerator yields makes the last member to satisfy the definition of the correlation of **daily** returns. Therfore

```
Corr[X, Y] = Corr[x, y]
```

Becouse 252 could be substituded by any other constant, the correlations in invariant with the period of returns.

Notes:

1. The assumption that the covariance matrix of log returns scales with the *period* of such *returns* holds if the return of an asset is not correlated with past returns of the same or other assets, and, given an arbitrary period to measure returns, the covariances are the same whatever the start of such period.
2. Variance is a particular case of a covariance of a variable with itself: Cov(X, X) = Var(X). Therefore, if the covariance scales with the period of the returns, so must the variance.

Comment: PLZ. Check your equations, there are a few typos